# Maintaining x and y across screen sizes

Tags: android, screen

[image]

I have an imageview with a layout on top of it which has buttons added at specific x and y coordinates. How do i make sure that everything lines up the same on different screen sizes so the buttons are always in the same position relative to the image regardless of screen, also how to maintain all the positioning if the orientation is horizontal.

Comment: what is your current approach? paste your layout xml. 
also you can use Constraintlayout > Search.

Answer (score 0):

I actually built a class specifically or this. You can find it here:

https://gist.github.com/nathan-fiscaletti/190a660620f6130e6a15962f59b21f22

The way you would use it is as follows:

Replace the `ImageView` in your layout with `SizeAwareImageView`.

```xml
<com.my.app.SizeAwareImageView
        android:id="@+id/sizeAwareImageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewHeader"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/somePicture" />
```

You can then determine the placement of those objects and use use the following to figure out where to place them.

```java
PointF location = sizeAwareImageView.getScaledCoordinateWithPadding(new PointF(10f, 10f));

// place the object at the location
```

This will keep your objects at the same location based on the drawable applied to the image view. No matter what screen it is on, the `location` variable will always point to the same placement on the **image**.

I use this to store the location of map markers in a database, they can then be used to move a pin around a static map drawable regardless of what device they are displayed on.

```java
/**
 * Update the map markers location and display it.
 *
 * @param mapPinLocation The new location.
 */
private void updateMarker(final PointF mapPinLocation) {
    markerContainer.removeView(mapMarker);

    PointF location = mapImageView
            .getScaledCoordinateWithPadding(mapPinLocation, 100f);

    if (getContext() != null) {
        int markerSize = (int) DisplayUtil.dpToPx(25, getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp
                = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(markerSize, markerSize);

        // Android uses top left of the view for it's coords
        // so we need to center it at it's X/Y coords.
        if (location != null) {
            lp.topMargin = (int) location.y - (markerSize / 2);
            lp.leftMargin = (int) location.x - (markerSize / 2);
            mapMarker.setLayoutParams(lp);
            markerContainer.addView(mapMarker);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is actually what you were looking for.

Comment: just for clarification is the new PointF(10f, 10f) replaced with my x and y coordinate i want to place? Also what is the multiplier value supposed to be

Comment: I believe the multiplier was incorrectly named and should have been named "scale_percentage", i might be wrong though. You should be able to tinker with it a little bit. And yes, the 10f, 10f should be the coordinates you want. However they may not be what you expect. If you tinker with it, find the coordinates you want and then store those, they will continue to work on all screen sizes.